# Do i require a queue for each consumer in rabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have the next problem, I have three programs and they should send a notification (message) to rabbitMQ when they modify a database, also each program should receive that notification so they know about that modification to the database.

I am new on using rabbitMQ so I don't know the way of working, I kinda understand the "hello world" tutorial on the official page and when I tried to use it (one queue) with multiple consumers, only one of them received the notification, so I am guessing I need to use a queue for each consumer but I want to know if that is the correct way to work with rabbitMQ in this situation.

As extra information about my project, I need each consumer to receive the last message sent, they should not care about past messages, so if a consumer is not available when it begins working it should not receive the spam of all the past notifications.

Comment: It sounds like you may have implemented a [work queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html), where each message goes to only one consumer. But you probably want [publish-and-subscribe](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) instead. See [this page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) for an overview, including more flexible variations, such as topics.

Comment: Publish and subscribe is the one i need it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need a queue for each consumer.

You can use fanout exchange

```cs
channel.ExchangeDeclare("database", ExchangeType.Fanout);
```

and regarding your "extra information"

> As extra information about my project, I need each consumer to receive the last message sent, they should not care about past messages, so if a consumer is not available when it begins working it should not receive the spam of all the past notifications.

You can use  a non-durable, exclusive, autodelete "Temporary queue" as suggested in the official tutorial [on this page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html)

```cs
channel.QueueDeclare();
```

Here are two quotes from this page:

1. > ... We're also interested only in currently flowing messages not in the old ones.
2. > ... whenever we connect to Rabbit we need a fresh, empty queue. To do this we could create a queue with a random name, or, even better - let the server choose a random queue name for us.

And then finally bind the queue to the exchange:

```cs
channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, exchange: "database", routingKey: "");
```

All together:

```cs
channel.ExchangeDeclare("database", ExchangeType.Fanout);
var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                  exchange: "database",
                  routingKey: "");
```

Of course each program will have a publisher logic, and subscriber logic.
And if we named the 3 programs with "A", "B" & "C", and then use the online simulator tool http://tryrabbitmq.com/, we get the following [image: routing topology]

==============

### Hint

In the future you might want to differentiate between different types of database changes (e.g. schema changed, data changed)
For that i would use a "database" topic exchange and routing keys per notification type. 
The rest will stay the same:

```cs
channel.ExchangeDeclare("database", ExchangeType.Topic);
var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                  exchange: "database",
                  routingKey: "schema.changed");
```

Comment: Really complete answer, already tested the code and looks fine, thanks for making me understand.